# Algebraic identity involving powers of twin primes

Tags: binomial-coefficients, twin-primes

Yesterday, I verified that, if $a$,$b$ and $c$ are real numbers such that $a+b+c=0$, then

$$\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}=\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$$

and

$$\frac{a^7+b^7+c^7}{7}=\frac{a^5+b^5+c^5}{5}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$$

Then I asked myself: will it be true that

$$\frac{a^{p_n}+b^{p_n}+c^{p_n}}{p_n}=\frac{a^{p_{n-1}}+b^{p_{n-1}}+c^{p_{n-1}}}{p_{n-1}}\cdot\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$$

for any pair of primes satifying $p_n=p_{n-1}+2$, i.e., for any pair of twin primes?

For the first two equalities, I wrote $a=-(b+c)$, expanded the powers $-(b+c)^x$ for $x=2,3,5,7$, multiplied the factors at the right hand side and verified that the left and right hand sides were equal. For the general case, I'm trying to do the same, but I'm having some difficulties. For the left hand side we have

$$-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p_n-1}{{p_n}\choose{i}}b^ic^{p_n-i}}{p_n}$$

and for the right hand side we have

$$-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{p_{n-1}-1}{{p_{n-1}}\choose{i}}[b^{i+2}c^{p_{n-1}-i}+b^{i+1}c^{p_{n-1}+1-i}+b^ic^{p_{n-1}+2-i}]}{p_{n-1}}$$

Note that we can cancel the minus sign. For the term $bc^{p_n-1}$ we have at the left hand side

$$\frac{{p_n}\choose{1}}{p_n}bc^{p_n-1}=\frac{p_n-1}{p_n-1}bc^{p_n-1}$$

and at the right hand side

$$\frac{{p_{n-1}}\choose{1}}{p_{n-1}}bc^{p_{n-1}+2-1}=\frac{p_{n-1}-1}{p_{n-1}-1}bc^{p_n-1}$$

Note that $p_n-1=p_{n-1}+1$. So this term, as well as $b^{p_n-1}c$, is OK. But I can't handle the other terms.

My questions are, is this identity known to be true? If so, how can I manipulate the right hand side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\weird}[4]{\dfrac{{#1}^{#4}+{#2}^{#4}+{#3}^{#4}}{#4}}$
I'd say your suggestion is false, because

$$\weird {(-y-z)}yz{13}-\weird {(-y-z)}yz{11}\cdot\weird {(-y-z)}yz2=\\=-y^3z^3(y+z)^3(y^2+yz+z^2)^2\ne0$$

It's always worth [checking the first hard case with a calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28-y-z%29%5E13%2By%5E13%2Bz%5E13%29%2F13-%28%28-y-z%29%5E11%2By%5E11%2Bz%5E11%29%28%28-y-z%29%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%29%2F22).

Comment: That's true. I just made a fortran program, and it's not valid for (17,19) and neither for (29,31). The question now is, what is so special about (3,5) and (5,7) for the indentity to hold (as I suppose) only for them? Maybe because they're the only pair of twin primes less than 10?

Comment: I was wondering as well, but as of now I thought of no good reason to explain those two identities. Perhaps there is.